# How to validate/restrict the item that's being dropped into a cart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

There are certain items, which are restricted quantity one to be dropped into the cart. Few other items, which can be dropped in multiple quantities.

I am able to restrict any item to be quantity one using following code.

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    if($("#cart ol:contains('"+ui.draggable.text()+"')").length > 0)
        { 
           //alert and do something
        }
```

I wrote another line of if condition, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
&& (ui.draggable.closest('div') !='200g Greens'))
```

Every item is in a different category under the catalogue. These categories are the `div` wrapping them. So items in one particular category can be added more than once (sale item), where as rest can't be added more than once.

Comment: you should use  $( ".trp" ).draggable({ revert: true }); https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#revert

Comment: @vel will `revert.true` allow the item to be placed in the box in the first place?